# Can I make a *.desktop item always be maximized?

Tags: launcher, gnome-terminal, window-management

Is there anything I can add to a *.desktop file (used in my Launcher panel) to make the application always open maximized?  In particular, I'm looking at the `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gnome-terminal` has an undocumented `--maximize` option (and also `--full-screen`).  You can add that to the launcher's EXEC line to have it start maximized.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I had tried `--full-screen`, but I didn't like the way it worked; not easy to move between multiple monitors, or un-maximize if I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gnome-terminal --full-screen` in the Exec of your desktop file to start gnome-terminal full screen.